# Can I have CA with JSSE

Tags: certificate-authority, openssl, java

Maybe the title isn't correct but what I am trying to understand is...

I want to create a certificate for my CA which will be self-signed and then create certificates for my clients and my server. Is this possible with [JSSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Secure_Socket_Extension)? I have found how to do that with OpenSSL only.

Comment: This is a Java-specific question and you might get better answers on StackOverflow.

Comment: "my CA" - does that mean you run your own CA?

Comment: no! I just want to create a certificate for the CA that is self-signed.

Comment: I might be suffering from a Monday thing, but that statement doesn't make a lot of sense to me. Can you restate it in another way to help clarify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSSE is the support for SSL/TLS. It *uses* certificates but includes no code for *generating* certificates. And, more generally, there is no code in the stock JVM that supports producing new certificates. There is code for generating new key pairs and signing; from there, making self-signed certificates is "just" a matter of implementing some ASN.1 encoding/decoding, which is easier said than done.

Your best bet, in "full Java", is to use some third-party library or product that does the job. [Bouncy Castle](https://www.bouncycastle.org/java.html) is a Java library that includes code for generating certificates. Alternatively, [EJBCA](https://www.ejbca.org/) is a complete PKI solution (written in Java) that, by definition, can generate certificates, because that's what Certification Authorities do.

The biggest hurdle with certificates is understanding what you are doing, because [the X.509 standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280) is, when you come down to it, a Devil-spawned abomination meant to torture and fill with despair and sorrow security developers. What you want to do is, indeed, to run your own CA, so you'd better start with a CA solution which already irons out most of the tricky details, contrary to the OpenSSL command-line tool, which is rather low-level. You will still need to think, but at least you won't go mad in the attempt.